# Function to return a list of strings as a proper case

Tags: python

I need to write a function which should be completed in 1 or 2 lines and should not use control statements.

Requirement is

Given a list of first names , capitalize them properly

> ex : ["JAMES", "jack","HArry"] should return["James","Jack","Harry"]

Hint : use a built in function and one of the string module functions to make this happen

Comment: Is this supposed to be a contest?

Comment: Use `dir()` and `dir(str)` to see what methods you could use.

Comment: What exactly do you consider a control statement? Have you made ANY attempt to do this yourself?

Comment: sounds a bit mean but I am trying to help my niece through this forum...I have never worked in Python but am a developer of Java, J2EE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> [x.title() for x in ["JAMES", "jack","HArry"]]
['James', 'Jack', 'Harry']
```

without control statement

```
>>> map(str.title, ["JAMES", "jack","HArry"])
['James', 'Jack', 'Harry']
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response but it was asked not to use control statements

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
i = 0
while i<len(list):
    list[i] = list[i].title()
    i += 1
```

Comment: Infinite loop. Also, too many lines.

Comment: No control statements allowed.

Answer (score 0):

```
def capitalize(*args):
    return map(str.capitalize, args)


print capitalize("JAMES", "jack", "HArry")
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response but it was asked not to use control statements

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> map(str.capitalize, ["JAMES", "jack", "HArry"])
['James', 'Jack', 'Harry']
```